# I want to write a test which checks that the component displaying a blog renders the blog's title and author,

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I want to write a test which checks that the component displaying a blog renders the blog's title and author, but does not render its url or number of likes by default.

**Here is my test code**

```
 import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import Blog from './Blog'
import { element } from 'prop-types'

describe('tests', () => {
  const blog = {
    title:'We are best',
    author:'Rev',
    url:'something.com',
    likes:3
  }

  test('checks if url and likes are not rendered by default', () => {

    const component = render(
      <Blog blog={blog}/>
    )
    expect(component.container).toHaveTextContent(blog.title)
    expect(component.container).not.toHaveTextContent(blog.likes)
    component.debug()
    expect(component.container).not.toHaveTextContent('something.com')
  })
})
```

**the component it tests:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Togglable from './Togglable'

const Blog = ({ blog,updateBlog,removingBlog }) => {
  const blogStyle = {
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 2,
    border: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 5,
  }
  const addLike = () => {
    updateBlog({
      ...blog,
      likes: blog.likes + 1,
    })
  }

  return (
    <div style={blogStyle} className='blog'>
      {blog.title}
      <Togglable buttonLabel='show'>
        <div>
          {blog.author}
        </div>
         likes:{blog.likes} <button onClick={addLike}> like </button>
        <div>
          {blog.url}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => removingBlog(blog.id, blog.title)}>remove</button>
        </div>
      </Togglable>
    </div>
  )}

export default Blog
```

**the togglable component which handles the toggle to show or hide url/likes:**

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react'

const Togglable = (props) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

  const hideWhenVisible = { display : visible ? 'none' : '' }
  const showWhenVisible = { display : visible ? '' : 'none' }

  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setVisible(!visible)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={hideWhenVisible}>
        <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>{props.buttonLabel}</button>
      </div>

      <div style={showWhenVisible}>
        {props.children}
        <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>cancel </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Togglable
```

**Snapshot of test**
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaXSY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `screen` instead of `component`, because `screen`takes into account `style='display: none'`. The following example can be found at [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screen).

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'

render(
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="example">Example</label>
    <input id="example" />
  </div>,
)

const exampleInput = screen.getByLabelText('Example')
```

Also, have you tried asking [the Discord-channel](https://study.cs.helsinki.fi/discord/join/fullstack) of [the course](https://fullstackopen.com/en/) that exercise is from.